# Underscore and needs to create multiple order for an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

2 questions :

I got an object which include 2 arrays like this :

```
{"iOS":["iPad","iPhone","iPhone6","iPad Mini"],"Android":["Galaxy S6","Galaxy S4"],"BlackBerry":["BlackBerry3"]}
```

How can I build with underscore a single object like this :

```
myobject = {"iPad" : 0,"iPhone3": 0,"iPhone6" :0 ,"iPad Mini" :0, "Galaxy S6": 0,"Galaxy S4" :0, "BlackBerry3" : 0}
```

Second questions, once I have my object like this :

```
myobject = {
"iPad" : 12,
"iPhone3": 0,
"iPhone6" :4 ,
"iPad Mini" :3, 
"Galaxy S6": 1,
"Galaxy S4": 14,
"BlackBerry3" : 1
}
```

How can I order it by descending value to get

```
myobject = {
"Galaxy S4" :14,
"iPad" : 12,
"iPhone6" :4 ,
"iPad Mini" :3, 
"Galaxy S6" :1, 
"iPhone3": 0, 
"BlackBerry3" : 0
}
```

thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't order object properties. You will need to use alternative data structure, like array of objects.

For example you can built such a structure with this code:

```
var myObject = _.chain(data).values().flatten().map(function(el) {
    return {
        type: el,
        count: 0
    };
}).value();
```

It will look like this:

```
[{"type":"iPad","count":0},{"type":"iPhone","count":0}, ... ];
```

Then it's easy to sort it with [_.sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) function:

```
_.sortBy(myObject, 'count');
```

**UPD.** If you really want to create an *object*, then this is how you can do it:

```
var myObject = _.chain(data).values().flatten().reduce(function(prev, curr) { 
    prev[curr] = 0; 
    return prev; 
}, {}).value();
```

This will give

```
{"iPad":0,"iPhone":0,"iPhone6":0,"iPad Mini":0,"Galaxy S6":0,"Galaxy S4":0,"BlackBerry3":0}
```

Comment: How can I build with underscore a single object like this :

`myobject = {"iPad" : 0,"iPhone3": 0,"iPhone6" :0 ,"iPad Mini" :0, "Galaxy S6": 0,"Galaxy S4" :0, "BlackBerry3" : 0}`

Comment: your function return `[{"count": 0, "type": 1}, {"count": 0, "type": 3}, {"count": 0, "type": 1}, {"count": 0, "type": 3}, {"count": 0, "type": 8}]`

Comment: I know, this is the preferred structure. Otherwise you will not be able to sort it. But if you want object check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found away to fix my problem.

dfsk helped me to find the logic, I just fixed his function :

```
var new_myobject = _.chain(myobject).map(function(num, key) {
     return {
          type: key,
          count: num
     };
}).sortBy('count').reverse().value();
```